# Azure Function searches File in a Wrong Place

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment, kudu

I have an Azure Function (C# v3) that uses a local text file located at `.\Assets\somefile.txt`. The file has property `Copy always` and is properly seen when running on my local machine. However, when deployed to Azure Function app, the file is expectedly located in `C:\home\site\wwwroot\Assets\somefile.txt` but the running function does not see it and writes an error log message `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.1.3\32bit\Assets\somefile.txt'.`

How can I make the function to see the file without hard coding the complete path to the file (it is different on my local machine anyway and I want to understand the actual root cause of the issue).

Comment: Please share code you're using to access the file?

Comment: The only line of code that uses the file is kind of `await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine("Assets", "somefile.txt"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to get the function execution root path. One is to add an [`ExecutionContext` parameter](https://jurgenonazure.com/2020/06/quick-tip-using-executioncontext-in-azure-functions/) in your function method and read the `FunctionAppDirectory` value.

```
public static string Run(TimerInfo timer, ExecutionContext context)
{

    var executionRoot = context.FunctionAppDirectory;
    var filePath = Path.Combine(executionRoot, "Assets", "somefile.txt");
    
    ...
}
```

Alternatively construct the base path from the `HOME` environment variable:

```
public static string Run(TimerInfo timer)
{

    var executionRoot = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")}/site/wwwroot";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(executionRoot, "Assets", "somefile.txt");
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx! `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory` indeed shows the expected `C:\home\site\wwwroot` for Azure Function app as well as the correct folder for the local machine.